# Need Help With Fixing GRUB Dualboot Windows7 and Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a running Windows 7 and installed Precise along with it just this afternoon. I was doing a manual partition configuration.

On the part where I get to set what partition to install the bootloader/MBR I chose the Windows partition. Now every time I choose Windows 7 from GRUB, it just reverts back to the GRUB menu.

I've been reading around the web as I type this and found this tool 'Bootinfo' to let you see my configuration. Here's the pastebin: [Boot Info](http://pastebin.com/izsyh9DD)

Any help would do. Thanks!

Comment: According to the boot info output, you've put the grub bootloader on /dev/sda2.  Grub needs to go into the MBR of /dev/sda, not into one of the partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use windows 7 dvd to repair the boot. Use bootsect.exe `fixboot` and `fixmbr` ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392#method1 )

Once it fixes windows 7, use ubuntu live cd/usb to boot. Then use `boot-repair` tool. [Instruction here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)